# Verifiable computing?

Tags: mining

[Verifiable computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verifiable_computing) is computing where the worker provides the clients with not only the result of the program, but a proof that those are the correct results (i.e. they didn't just fudge them so they wouldn't have to do any work). In Ethereum, AFAICT, verification is done by having miners re-run the program entirely. However, for some simple programs, it's possible to do the verification quickly and securely (e.g.
 [Non-interactive verifiable computing: Outsourcing computation to untrusted workers](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-642-14623-7_25.pdf)). The protocol in the paper I linked only works for boolean circuits, but it provides input/output privacy, and the verification time scales with the size of the input, not the size of the circuit.

My question is, does Ethereum plan to support verifiable computing protocols similar to the one I linked in order to speed up verification / provide privacy? If not, are there any other cryptocurrencies that do?